# How to retrieve s3 bucket tags using data source in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an s3 bucket with some tags associated with it. I would like to use data source to retrieve the tags. The terraform documentation does not talk about it. The aws_s3_bucket data source does not return tags. It only returns the following attributes: arn,bucket,bucket_domain_name,bucket_regional_domain_name,hosted_zone_id,id,region,website_domain,website_endpoint.

How do I retrieve the tags associated with a s3 bucket using datasource?

I am using terraform v1.5.5
hashicorp/aws v4.67.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the s3 bucket data source does not support tags (as we can infer from the source code https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/main/internal/service/s3/bucket_data_source.go) . I suggest you open a GitHub issue for this.

As an alternative, you can use an external data source which uses the `aws` cli and `jq`.

Given `util.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
tags=$(aws s3api get-bucket-tagging --bucket "$1" --output json)
jq -r -n --argjson tags "$tags" '{"tags":($tags|tojson)}'
```

and `main.tf`:

```
data "aws_s3_bucket" "selected" {
  bucket = "mybucket"
}

data "external" "util" {
  program = ["bash","util.sh","${data.aws_s3_bucket.selected.id}"]
}

output "tags" {
  value = data.external.util.result.tags
}
```

```bash
$ terraform apply
...

$ terraform console
> data.external.util.result.tags
"{\"TagSet\":[{\"Key\":\"organization\",\"Value\":\"marketing\"}]}"
> jsondecode(data.external.util.result.tags)
{
  "TagSet" = [
    {
      "Key" = "organization"
      "Value" = "marketing"
    },
  ]
}
```

so as you can see the output of the external data source is a JSON encoded string which needs to be decoded.